# NoMethodError: undefined method `generate' for Roo::CSV:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, roo-gem

I try to made a scheduled daily csv mail.
I put inside my Importer class:
" include Roo"
then I put 2 functions:

```
def self.daily_mail
  Company.find_each do |c|
    export_to_csv(c)
  end
end

def self.export_to_csv(company)
  @opportunities = company.opportunities
  csv_data = CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv <<  ["Opportunity Id", "Created At", "Request Id", "Champion Id", "Referral_Id"]
    @opportunities.all.each do |opportunity|
      csv << [opportunity.id, opportunity.created_at, opportunity.request_id, opportunity.champion_id, opportunity.referral_id]
    end
  end
end
```

And in the scheduler class I coded:

```
task :export => :environment do
  puts "Exporting..."
    Importer.daily_mail
  puts "done."
end
```

However, when I tried to run in my terminal:

```
rake export
```

I got:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `generate' for Roo::CSV:Class
```

Can someone help me pleas?

Comment: in the `roo` gem there is no `generate` method for `csv` but there is new method to create a csv

Comment: If you want to use [CSV.generate](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-generate) from standard library, you may need to add `require 'csv'` to Importer file

Comment: @RajarshiDas can you explain what do you mean ?

Comment: @vanHuy I tried to add "require" seems its not work ///

Comment: I guess it calls CSV from Roo by default, so to use CSV from standard library please try `::CSV.generate` instead

Comment: @VanHuy thank you !!!!!! it's works:)

Comment: @yardench I posted a full answer for this. Please consider accepting it if it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you need Roo here, but only for exporting csv file, the standard [CSV library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) is enough. [CSV.generate](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-generate) is a method from standard library, so to use this, you have to add `require 'csv'` to Importer file.

You also need to remove "include Roo" to avoid conflict. But if you still want to work with Roo, please replace `CSV.generate` by `::CSV.generate`.